# I am facing the session conflict Error in my shoping cart application of my website

Tags: asp.net, web-services

i am using the code below to maintain the Cart.There is an error in session that while i am opening my website in more then to browser there is session conflict that when i select the item from my one browser and then to another so the previously created session updated
,though there has to be the new session for each browser
Please some one help me to understand the region of the Error in session.

```
#region Singleton Implementation

    // Readonly properties can only be set in initialization or in a constructor
    public static readonly ShoppingCart Instance;
    // The static constructor is called as soon as the class is loaded into memory
    static ShoppingCart()
    {
        // If the cart is not in the session, create one and put it there
        // Otherwise, get it from the session     
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ShoppingCart"] == null)
        {
            Instance = new ShoppingCart();
            Instance.Items = new List<CartItem>();
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("ShoppingCart", Instance);
        }
        else
        {
            Instance = (ShoppingCart)HttpContext.Current.Session["ShoppingCart"];
        }
    }

    // A protected constructor ensures that an object can't be created from outside
    protected ShoppingCart() { }

    #endregion
```

Answer (score 1):

The static constructor will be called `only once`. so the else will never execute.

Instead of this implementation ,you can use a property that checks if the session is null it creates an instance , else it returns the stored one.

```
public Instance
{
set{ ... }
get{ ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that there is the problem in ShopingCart Class Constructor 
While i was using the static constructor directly i becomes global that's way my shoping cart data shared with the other user shoping cart
but now i am using the property of the objects .That is like this,

**The Main things is the return type in the if statement of the get  property **

```
 public static ShoppingCart Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ShoppingCart"] == null)
            {
                // we are creating a local variable and thus
                // not interfering with other users sessions
                ShoppingCart instance = new ShoppingCart();
                instance.Items = new List<CartItem>();
                HttpContext.Current.Session["ShoppingCart"] = instance;
                return instance;
            }
            else
            {
                // we are returning the shopping cart for the given user
                return (ShoppingCart)HttpContext.Current.Session["ShoppingCart"];
            }
        }
    }
```